# Linq over datatable using dynamic library sample?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am looking for sample linq code snippet which uses System.Linq.Dynamic against a datatable.

```
Dim entities = (From ent In dt.AsEnumerable().Where(String.Format("IsUSFederal == {0}", "true")) _
Select Description = ent("Description"), Acronym = ent("Acronym")).ToList
```

I am getting an error "there is no accessible Where can be called with these arguments".  I have included the DynamicLinq.vb file and the application compiles fine (aside from this error).  I have included Imports System.Linq.Dynamic but it doesn't appear to be working.

Any ideas?
thx

Comment: Can you post the code in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) takes a `Func(Of TSource, Boolean)` as argument and your passing a `String`.

*(update)*

Didn't catch the Dynamic library part ... sorry. I think you need to do this:

```
dt.AsQueryable()
```

Because the extension methods on the library are defined as:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function Where(ByVal source As IQueryable, ByVal predicate As String, 
                      ByVal ParamArray values() As Object) As IQueryable
```

Comment: I am trying to use the linq extensions in http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx
but something is not quite right as it seems the .Where in the extension is not being used

Comment: If you do OrderBy, you need to first do dt.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()